# How to get element count in multiple xml files in a folder using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, count

The following php script gives count of elements in a single xml file in the folder **uploads**. But I have number of xml files in the folder. What to modify in the following script so that I get result in tabular format with the file name and element count for all the xml files in the folder.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$xml = simplexml_load_file("uploads/test.xml");
//file to SimpleXMLElement 
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($xml);
print("Number of elements: ".$xml->count());    
?>
```

Comment: How to read the content of a directory and loop over it in PHP, should be easy enough to research, if you don't know how. So start with that, would be my suggestion.

Comment: Well I suggest  you will have to write a loop of some sort. I woudl start by looking at the [PHP manual](https://php.net) for the GLOB() function

Comment: get the count of each file, and add them up. It's unclear how/where/why you're getting stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're first loading the XML file into a `SimpleXMLElement` then import it into a `DOMElement` and call the method `count()` on it. This method does not exists on `DOMElement` - only on `SimpleXMLElement`. So the import would not be necessary.

You can use a `GlobIterator` to iterate the files:

```
$directory = __DIR__.'/uploads';

// get an iterator for the XML files
$files = new GlobIterator(
  $directory.'/*.xml', FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO
);

$results = [];
foreach ($files as $file) {
  // load file using absolute file path 
  // the returned SimpleXMLElement wraps the document element node
  $documentElement = simplexml_load_file($file->getRealPath());
  $results[] = [
    // file name without path
    'file' => $file->getFilename(),
    // "SimpleXMLElement::count()" returns the number of children of an element
    'item-count' => $documentElement->count(),
  ];
}

var_dump($results);
```

With DOM you can use Xpath to fetch specific values from the XML.

```
$directory = __DIR__.'/uploads';

// get an iterator for the XML files
$files = new GlobIterator(
  $directory.'/*.xml', FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO
);

// only one document instance is needed
$document = new DOMDocument();

$results = [];
foreach ($files as $file) {
  // load the file into the DOM document
  $document->load($file->getRealPath());
  // create an Xpath processor for the loaded document
  $xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
  $results[] = [
    'file' => $file->getFilename(),
    // use an Xpath expression to fetch the value
    'item-count' => $xpath->evaluate('count(/*/*)'),
  ];
}

var_dump($results);
```

#### The Xpath Expression

- Get the document element `/*`
- Get the child elements of the document element `/*/*`
- Count them `count(/*/*)`

`*` is an universal selector for any element node. If you can you should be more specific and use the actual element names (e.g. `/list/item`).

Answer (score 2):

First, create a `function` with the logic you have:

```
function getXML($path) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($path);
    //file to SimpleXMLElement 
    $xml = simplexml_import_dom($xml);
    return $xml;
}
```

Note that I:

- have converted the path into a parameter, so you can reuse the same logic for your files
- separated the parsing of XML from showing it
- returned the XML itself, so you can get the count or you can do whatever else you may want with it

This is how you can get the files of a given path:

```
$files = array_diff(scandir('uploads'), array('.', '..'));
```

we get all files except for `.` and `..`, which are surely not of interest here. Read more about scandir here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

You received an array of filenames on success, so, let's loop it and perform the logic you need:

```
$xmls = [];
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (str_ends_with($file, '.xml')) {
        $xmls[] = $file . "\t" . getXML('uploads/' . $file)->count();
    }
}
echo implode("\n", $xmls);
```

EDIT

As @Juan kindly explained in the comment section, one can use

```
$files = glob("./uploads/*.xml");
```

instead of `scandir` and that would ensure that we no longer need a call for `array_diff` and later we can avoid the `if` inside the loop:

```
$xmls = [];
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $xmls[] = $file . "\t" . getXML('uploads/' . $file)->count();
}
echo implode("\n", $xmls);
```

Comment: Getting the following error -

**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function str_ends_with()

on line  

if (str_ends_with($file, '.xml')) {

Comment: @GurusGuru this function should exist in PHP 8, see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ends-with.php

Comment: Why don't use `$files = glob("./uploads/*.xml");` instead of `scandir` ....?

Comment: @Juan I have no particular preference for `scandir` over `glob`. Is there a particular reason why you would prefer `glob` in this case?

Comment: Yes on this script I would rather use blob(), so as not to have to use additional code among other things.
Additional code to remove "." And ".."
Additional code to only process XML files.

Comment: @Juan you mean to avoid the call for `array_diff`?

Comment: Yes and `str_ends_with()`

Comment: @Juan thanks for making a good point! Using `glob` certainly helps in making the code easier to read. Edited my answer to illustrate this idea.

Comment: @GurusGuru happy to help! You may consider accepting this answer as the correct one and/or upvoting Juan's comments, which also contributed to it.